# Why is BigInt(largeNumber) still not precise?

Tags: javascript, bigint

I want to find the sum of all digits of a large number, for example 99<sup>95</sup>.

I applied BigInt to get the power of large number and sum its digits together using the code below.

```js
BigInt(Math.pow(99, 95)).toString().split("").reduce((a, b) => a * 1 + b * 1)
```

However, it returns `845`, but the correct answer should be `972`.

I have checked the integer output of the large number. In JavaScript it is:

`3848960788934848488282452569509484590776195611314554049114673132510910096787679715604422673797115451807631980373077374162416714994207463122539142978709403811688831410945323915071533162168320`

This is not the same as the correct answer (in C#):

`3848960788934848611927795802824596789608451156087366034658627953530148126008534258032267383768627487094610968554286692697374726725853195657679460590239636893953692985541958490801973870359499`.

I am wondering what’s wrong in my code causing the differences.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression `Math.pow(99, 95)`, when it resolves, has already lost precision - casting it to a BigInt after the fact does not recover the lost precision.

Use BigInts from the beginning instead, and use `**` instead of `Math.pow` so that the exponentiation works:

```js
console.log(
  (99n ** 95n)
    .toString()
    .split('')
    .reduce((a, b) => a + Number(b), 0)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

`BigInt(Math.pow(99,95))`

This runs math pow on 2 floats, then converts it to bigint.

You want `BigInt(99) ** BigInt(95)` instead